# Are SQL engines optimized that far ? (see example)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

Let's say I query the DB as follows :

```
SELECT
   T3.ID
   T1.factor1 * T2.factor2  * T3.VAL,
   T1.factor1 * T2.factor2  * T3.VAL,
   T1.factor1 * T2.factor2  * T3.VAL,
   T1.factor1 * T2.factor2  * T3.VAL,
               (...)
   T1.factor1 * T2.factor2  * T3.VAL
FROM
   Table3 AS T3
   LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T3.ID = T2.Table3ID
   LEFT JOIN Table1 AS T1 ON T3.ID = T1.Table3ID
```

My question is :

will the engine perform `T1.factor1 * T2.factor2`, *once* or *N times* ?

(please give answers relevant to your DB engine of choice!)

You can also give a more general answer (let's say there would be *P* factors instead of just 2.

EDIT : you could replace `T1.factor1 * T2.factor2` by any computationally intenstive function of your choice, that would have a distinct value for each output row.

Comment: It looks like all the items in the SELECT list are distinct - no dupes - what's your question then? All of these will be evaluated once, in what context are you expecting that they will be evaluated *N* times?

Comment: @Jodrell : added ! (but the question focuses on the factors :) )

Comment: @Charleh: there are dupes : for a given row of the output table, "T1.factor1 * T2.factor2" will be computed N times !

Comment: So you are saying does SQL evaluate T1.factor1 * T1.factor2 - that's not what's in the question - any chance you can remove the **T3.Field4** from your question as it would make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
   T1.factor1 * T2.factor2 * T3.FIELD1, 
   T1.factor1 * T2.factor2 * T3.FIELD2, 
   T1.factor1 * T2.factor2 * T3.FIELD3, 
   T1.factor1 * T2.factor2 * T3.FIELD4, 
               (...) 
   T1.factor1 * T2.factor2 * T3.FIELDN 
FROM 
   Table3 AS T3 
   LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2 
   LEFT JOIN Table1 AS T1
```

Not sure what the question is here - are you asking this because of the joins? Since all of your select expressions are different, I'd guess that your query relates to the joins

My question is - why would the DB engine evaluate the expression more than once? In what scenario are you expecting that this should happen more than once?

You are asking for a value from each table... what leads you to believe that SQL needs to do anything more than one thing to get a value from each one of these tables?

Edit: In light of the tweaks to the question - it's a good one. I don't think SQL will know to optimise this heavily since you were originally multiplying each field by a different field each time creating a different scalar operation.

I tried doing the same calulation 300 times vs another query which did it once - SQL didn't report any differences in query cost. Of course there's plenty more to look at - but I'd imagine either the difference was too small, or SQL is optimising this

[image: Query * 300 vs Query * 1]

This is on MSSQL 2005.

I'd try this on your own DB with something computationally expensive and compare query plans. Might be worth checking stats and other performance metrics

Comment: In fact the question is : does the engine evaluate several times a given formula (with constant output), if it is used for several columns of a given row ? Here, "T1.factor1 * T2.factor2" could be a "VERY_INTENSTIVE_COMPUATATION(CONSTi),", i.e., a function that would have a distinct value for each output row, but not for each output column in a given row.

Comment: I've updated taking into account what you've tweaked in your question

Comment: superb. Thanks for the try & exec plan !